# Android MVVM - Update ViewModel when data changes

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, rx-java

I'm working on an app using the `MVVM` pattern with `RxJava`. The architecture is the following:
[image]

It's the first time i use this pattern and i'm not sure about the best way to update a `ViewModel` (and consequently the corresponding `View`) when a change occurs in the data, made by another component of the application.

For example: suppose we have an `Activity` showing the list of users i follow (like a social app), from this list i select a user and open his profile in another `Activity`. Now, from this second `Activity` i decide to unfollow the user and when i press the back button to return to the first `Activity` i would like the list to be updated automatically (deleting the corresponding user, obviously without having to re-download all the data).

The problem is that the two `Activity` have two different `ViewModel`. How can i make the changes made by the second `Activity` affect the `ViewModel` of the first one? Is it the responsibility of the `Repository` to inform the first `Activity` of the changes?

- I'd rather not use `startActivityForResult`
- I'd rather not to inject the `ViewModel` of the first `Activity` in the second one

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> i decide to unfollow the user and when i press the back button to return to the first Activity i would like the list to be updated automatically (deleting the corresponding user, obviously without having to re-download all the data).
>
> The problem is that the two Activity have two different ViewModel.

I thought you have a Repository that wraps a "Model" (local datasource) that is able to expose `LiveData<*>`, no?

In which case all you need to do is this:

```
@Dao
public interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ITEMS")
    LiveData<List<Item>> getItemsWithChanges();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE ID = :id")
    LiveData<List<Item>> getItemWithChanges(String id);
}
```

Now your repository can return LiveData from the DAO:

```
public class MyRepository {
    public LiveData<List<Item>> getItems() {
        // either handle "fetch if needed" here, or with NetworkBoundResource
        return itemDao.getItemsWithChanges();
    }
}
```

Which you get in your ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final LiveData<List<Item>> items;

    public MyViewModel(MyRepository repository) {
        this.items = repository.getItems();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Item>> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

And if you observe this, then when you modify the item in Room, then it'll automatically update this LiveData in `onStart` (when you start observing again).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for! I mostly need to call remote APIs, but i can use a local datasource as a sort of cache.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce For "getItemWithChanges(String id)", how would I pass the id from the Activity to the ViewModel to the Repository, so that the Repository returns "itemDao.getItemsWithChanges(String Id);" to the Dao?

Comment: I'd probably pass it over in the `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

Comment: This should NOT be the accepted answer. There are various reasons why using Livedata in a repository is a bad idea.

Comment: @k1dbl4ck It's been 2 years and I still haven't seen one other than appeals to supposed architectural purity. Something about, 'you shouldn't let `androidx.*` related components leak into your data/"domain" layers'. In an app written for Android, that will never be re-used anywhere else on any other platform. If this is a concern for you, then just don't use Room, don't use LiveData, and write your entire app as a pure-`java` library as you would with a LibGDX core. But if you're writing Android apps for Android, then there's nothing wrong with LiveData inside Repository.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - this is not a "puritan" point of view, it has real world implications - LiveData observers are called on the main thread (not to mention it's bound to app lifecycle) - You can write code in SwahiliLang for that matter and still stall the main thread for an operation that should be async - google top pick explains it: https://proandroiddev.com/dont-use-livedata-in-repositories-f3bebe502ed3

Comment: This article is basically saying "we had a DAO with SQLite in it, we still did our filtering in code, we used `Transformations.map {}` despite it running on the UI thread, we did not do anything to apply multi-threading, now I blame LiveData for not working the way I thought it would". This is all resolved with `switchMap { liveData { withContext(IO) {` which ***was*** available at the time of writing of that article, so any appeal to "it runs on the UI thread" is actually not relevant, because it doesn't *have* to.