# How does the model communicate data changes to the view model in android mvvm?

Tags: android, mvvm

In Android MVVM,model(example:StockModel) hold many mutable data,maybe stock's realtime price,some viewmodels(called VM1 and VM2,they are not in one activity!) use StockModel,when VM1 invoke model to update realtime or model update realime self，how to notify VM2 realtime has change?

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316650/android-mvvm-update-viewmodel-when-data-changes

Comment: Another option is to add propertychange notification to your models, which you can do automatically with things like propertychanged.fody.